# Transaction Success but keep asking for password when download contents

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am hosted the contents on itunes connect and testing the IAP in both sandbox and beta-testing environment.

I don't have any issue on sandbox yesterday but it keep asks me to re-enter the password when startDownloads: is called and then failed the download (on both sandbox and beta).

Anyone knows how to resolve it?

The process:
- paymentQueue addPayment: to purchase product

- prompt for authorize payment
- user confirm payment
- payment success, startDownloads
- ask for password again (may be couple of times)
- failed download

I implement code follow this guide: http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/

startDownloads: when purchased or restored, then finishTransaction: when download completed

Comment: I am just experiencing this same problem in my code, that was working just fine ~14 days ago. Is the problem stil present in your project? I am guessing it has something to do with Apple's servers.

Comment: As a heads up, others are experiencing this problem as well for the past three days, as is evident from Apple Developer Forums:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1070816#1070816
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1070817#1070817

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of Apple's sandbox servers for Hosted Content currently being down. Everything works on production servers though.

I've tested this on my exact code that is on the App Store right now. It works when I download the app from there, but I am experiencing the same problem as you are when installing through Xcode and using sandbox environment.

The only thing to do now is wait until Apple fixes the problem on their end.